# Kernel-slim UBI docker image not working with springBootUtility

Tags: open-liberty

Team, Is it possible to use springBootUtility with OpenLiberty kernel-slim UBI images (e.g. - kernel-slim-java8-openj9-ubi) ?
https://openliberty.io/docs/21.0.0.7/reference/command/springbootUtility-thin.html

Because, it's giving an error as

> `Step 3/11 : RUN springBootUtility thin --sourceAppPath=/staging/fat-order-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar --targetThinAppPath=/staging/thin-order-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar --targetLibCachePath=/staging/lib.index.cache`
> `---> Running in 3023c669c4d7`
> **`/bin/sh: springBootUtility: command not found`**

The springBootUtility is only working with OpenLiberty full UBI images

Comment: It looks like you should specify the complete path to `springBootUtility`, or add the localization in it. `export PATH=$PATH:path_to_liberty/wlp/bin/` or something.

Comment: Thanks Chomel. I already tried with this and getting same error. Do you have any example that showing for kernel-slim ubi images because its working find fine and built using full docker image

Comment: the path might not be correctly defined in the thread. I do not know how. btw you should describe what you tried already to help the community.

Answer (score 3):

The `kernel-slim` image does not appear to have that command at all. Compare `kernel-slim`:

```
bash-5.1$ docker run --rm -it openliberty/open-liberty:kernel-slim-java8-openj9-ubi ls /opt/ol/wlp/bin
auditUtility      binaryLog.bat       productInfo      securityUtility.bat  serverSchemaGen
auditUtility.bat  featureUtility      productInfo.bat  server           serverSchemaGen.bat
binaryLog     featureUtility.bat  securityUtility  server.bat       tools
```

To `full`:

```
bash-5.1$ docker run --rm -it openliberty/open-liberty:full-java8-openj9-ubi ls /opt/ol/wlp/bin
auditUtility      binaryLog.bat  featureUtility      pluginUtility  securityUtility.bat  springBootUtility
auditUtility.bat  client     featureUtility.bat  pluginUtility.bat  server           springBootUtility.bat
batchManager      client.bat     jaxb            productInfo    server.bat       tools
batchManager.bat  ddlGen     jaxrs           productInfo.bat    serverSchemaGen
binaryLog     ddlGen.bat     jaxws           securityUtility    serverSchemaGen.bat
```

There appears to be a hole in the documentation, since nothing indicates you need to do this, but you need to install the `springBoot` feature into Open Liberty before the command will be added. Copy your server.xml with spring boot specified into the image, then run `features.sh`:

```
COPY --chown=1001:0 server.xml /config/
RUN features.sh
```

After that, `springBootUtility` will be placed in the `/opt/ol/wlp/bin` dir and should be on the path as well for further Dockerfile directives to use.

Comment: And here's a sample of this: https://github.com/OpenLiberty/ci.docker/blob/master/samples/spring-petclinic/